# Excel to PDF convertion not working after Onedrive Business Sync

Tags: excel, vba

I am using below code to change Excel extension to pdf and save the file same path. After onedrive business sync applied in my laptop, macro started to not working and skipping below code after if. so is there any known solution for it?

```
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    s(0) = ThisWorkbook.FullName

    If FSO.FileExists(s(0)) Then
        s(1) = FSO.GetExtensionName(s(0))
        If s(1) <> "" Then
            s(1) = "." & s(1)
            sNewFilePath = Replace(s(0), s(1), ".pdf")
                ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat _
                Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                FileName:=sNewFilePath, _
                Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
        End If
```

Comment: What's the value of `s(0)` when it fails?  If it's pointing to an http path then FSO can't check that file exists.

Comment: @TimWilliams it directly skipped if and goes next after end if. I am asking how can I replace that formula.

Comment: Can you answer my question though?

Comment: @TimWilliams   https:\\ link

Comment: Maybe look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47523521/vba-checking-folder-file-exist-in-sharepoint for approaches